# Interchange the order of summation in Dirichlet convolution

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, analytic-number-theory, alternative-proof

I'm doing the following exercise from Apostol's number theory book, a solution, or better a Hint would be welcome.

(Chapter 2 ex 14) Let $f(x)$ be defined for all rationals $x$ in $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and let

$$ F(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n f(k/n), \quad F^*(n) = \sum_{\substack k =  1 \\ (k, \,n)  =  1}^nf(k/n) $$

Prove that $F^* = \mu * F$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function and $*$ is the Dirichlet product.

**My attempt :**

$$ \mu * F = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \sum_{k = 1}^{n/d} f(k/(n/d)) $$

But the summation in the inner part is equal to
$$ \sum_{k \leq n/d} f(k/(n/d)) = \sum_{dk \leq n} f(dk/n) = \sum_{\substack t \leq n \\ d|t} f(t/n) $$

Using the last expresion in the sum of $\mu * F$ we get

$$ \mu *F = \sum_{d|n}\mu(d) \sum_{\substack t \leq n \\ d|t} f(t/n) $$

**Struggling here** (Trying to interchange the order of summation to make the $\mu(d)$ "go away").

Now for each $d|n$ we're summing all the $f(t/n)$ where $d|t$, So I can change the order of summation into all the $t$ less than $n$, and check all the $d$ that divide both $t$ and $n$

$$ \sum_{t \leq n} f(t/n) \sum_{\substack d|n \\ d|t} \mu(d) = \sum_{t \leq n} f(t/n) \sum_{ d|(t, n)} \mu(d) = \sum_{t \leq n} f(t/n) \lfloor 1/(t, n) \rfloor$$

And this last sum is the one over the $t$ relatively prime to $n$ which is what we were looking for.

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry but I'm not following, if the sum goes from $m$ to $n$ on $f(n/m)$ wouldn't this be a problem since the hypothesis doesn't state that $f$ is defined for $x > 1$?. Also, the sum that follows is the sum over $d, k$ such that $d|n$ and $m = kd$?

Comment: $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) F(d/n)=\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \sum_{k=1}^{n/d} f((kd)/n) =\sum_{m=1}^n f(m/n) \sum_{d, k, d |n, m = kd} \mu(d)$

$=\sum_{m=1}^n f(m/n) \sum_{d | gcd(m,n)} \mu(d)=\sum_{m=1, \gcd(m,n)=1}^n f(m/n) $